# Edit ASP.NET Core website in Docker container on Windows and run on Ubuntu VPN

Tags: linux, windows, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create a ASP.NET Core 2.0 website in a docker container and host it on a Linux VPS docker system. I tried creating an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in Visual Studio, and then publishing it to docker hub. Everything works great, until I want to run that docker image on my Linux environment. I then get an error saying that this image is created for windows or something equivalent. I know I need to create the asp.net project in the Linux environment, then start coding (obviously), but I want to do the coding in for example Visual Studio on *my* PC, not via PICO or some other ssh-connected editor.

Summarized:

```
- I wish to run ASP.NET Core 2.0 website on Linux Docker VPS environment.
- I (think I) need to create the project in the Linux environment (I run Windows locally). 
- Wish to edit the code in the docker container locally on my Windows environment.
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Before creating ASP.NET Core 2 website on your windows operating system, right click on the Docker icon in system tray and then click `Switch to Linux containers`. Once switched to Linux containers, create ASP.NET Core website that you can host on Linux.

Comment: Wow, had to idea it was this easy! Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Great! I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating ASP.NET Core 2 website on your windows operating system, right click on the Docker icon in system tray and then click `Switch to Linux containers`. Once switched to Linux containers, create ASP.NET Core website that you can host on Linux.

[image]